# Django: one template for different lists of objects

Tags: django, templates, foreign-keys

my model is basically a chain of objects linked by a foreign key:

```
class Object1(object):
    object1_id = models.AutoField()
    object1_name = models.CharField()

class Object2(object):
    object2_id = models.AutoField()
    object2_name = models.CharField()
    object1 = models.ForeignKey(Object1)

class Object3(object):
    object3_id = models.AutoField()
    object3_name = models.CharField()
    object2 = models.ForeignKey(Object2)
```

I want to able to display lists of objects per class, each line being a link to the list of the son objects. If an id is given, the list should only contain the objects whose parent have the given id. So in my view i have functions like these:

```
def object1(request):
    liste = Object1.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('list.html', {'list' : list, 'link' : link})                                                 

def object2(request, id):                                                              
    if id == 0:                                                                  
           list = Object2.objects.all() 
           link = "object3"                 
           render_to_response('list.html', {'list' : list, 'link' : link})

    else:                                                                            
            liste = Object2.objects.filter(object1 = id)                              
            return render_to_response('list.html', {'list':list, 'link':link})
```

the problem is that i don't know **how to create a single template able to display these list**:

```
    {% for ele in list %}
            <li><a href="/{{link}}/{{ele.id}}/">{{ele.name}}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
```

doesn't work because the id and te name of the object is different in each case.
By the way if anybody has **an idea of how to create one view to do the job**, it would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any reason why you need to have different names for the same attributes in different models? It seems unnecessary. In fact, I wonder why you need different models at all.

If you really do need to do this, I suggest you add properties to each of the models to get their name and id values:

```
@property
def name(self):
    return self.object1_name
```

and so on - now you can simply do `{{ ele.name }}` in the template.